# Returning a dictionary from prepare_field

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm setting up ElasticSearch, and would like to index multiple fields from a related object by name. How would you do this in a proper way?
My index looks like this:

```
class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    updatedAt = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='updatedAt')
    date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date', null=True)
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')

    annotations = indexes.CharField(faceted=True)
    companies = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True)
```

Now i would like to acces companies as a dictionary, so in my templates i could do something like:

```
{% for comp in companies %} 
 {{ comp.dnbNumber }}
 {{ comp.primaryName }}
{% endfor %}
```

So far i tried:

```
def prepare_companies(self, obj):
        return [{company['dnbNumber'], company['primaryName'], company['cleanName']} for company in obj.companies.all()
                .values('dnbNumber', 'primaryName', 'cleanName')]

def prepare_companies(self, obj):
        companies = [(company['dnbNumber'], company['primaryName'], company['cleanName']) for company in obj.companies.all()
                .values('dnbNumber', 'primaryName', 'cleanName')]
 return [{'dnbNumber': comp[0], 'primaryName': comp[1], 'cleanName':comp[2]} for comp in companies]
```

If been searching google for answers but failed to find any.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm verry new to Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

To map django models to elasticsearch indeces I'd recommend using [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl).

It also allows to index all info you need about your FKs and reverse relations.

Example from docs:

```
@car.doc_type
class CarDocument(DocType):
    ads = fields.NestedField(properties={
        'description': fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip),
        'title': fields.TextField(),
        'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    })
```